# How to check the number of times the back button is pressed in android

Tags: android

I am aware that a method `onBackPressed()` exists in java to handle code when back button is pressed.

But I want to know if there is any method or variable which tells me the number of time the back button is pressed?

Comment: Add a counter when ever you get to the function

Comment: Can you tell the code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int counter;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed(); //remove this line if you don't want to finish the activity on back press

    counter++;
    System.out.println("Back button pressed for" + counter + "times.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `counter` variable and increment it in the `onClick()`

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
 counter++;
 myText.setText(“You click the Button “+count+” times now”);
}}
```